# Domain of uniqueness and singular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find domains of uniqueness and a singular solution for the following differential equation:
$$y'x=9y+3xy^{\frac{2}{3}}$$
General solution:
$$y=C^3x^9-\frac{3}{2}C^2x^7+\frac{3}{4}Cx^5-\frac{x^3}{8}$$
Domains of uniqueness:
$$f(x,y)=9\frac{y}{x}+3y^{\frac{2}{3}}\ \implies\ x <0\ or\ x>0 $$
$$f'(x,y)_y = \frac{9}{x}+\frac{2}{y^{\frac{1}{3}}}\ \implies\ x <0\ or\ x>0,\ y \neq 0 $$
I think that the singular solution is $y=0$. I'm right?

How can I prove that the uniqueness condition is violated at all points of the solution $y = 0$?

Edit:

It seems so:
$$y=0\ ,\ y=(-\frac{x}{2}+(\frac{1}{2x_0})x^3)^3$$